# Website URL redirects to name/%20/auth/login

Tags: .htaccess, web, html

I have a website which is hosted on godaddy. When i enter the url thehotkey.in, the url redirects to thehotkey.in/%20/auth/login gives me a blank page.

When i go to : thehotkey.in/auth/login, it gives me a distorted login form. 
Every button i click on , example, if i were to click on to register button on this login page, it redirects to thehotkey.in/%20/auth/register which gives me a blank page.

If i go to thehotkey.in/index, it gives me a blank page as well.

There is some sort of mis-redirection but I cant figure out how to tackle it.

Here is my.htaccess for more help:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ [L]
</IfModule>
```

( I didnt write the code, its a bought  code)

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The base Url in the fx_cpnfig file had a space at the end of the url address. Due to this, we sae %20 in every redirected url . Everything was alright after removing the space.